# Loop a fourier calculation and export each tested parameter to a mutiple column csv-file

Tags: export

I want to evaluate the code below for a series of s, running s from for example 1 to 100, or with s being a list of specific numbers in a list such as {5,7,10, etc}. I have attached a small sample of data.

The result for each evaluation, thus for each individual s in the series, should be exported into a separate column in a csv file.

In the attached notebook, as you see, I have set s to 5, thus exporting the resulting cosine projected 5000 steps into a single column csv. So far I have found the command Do:

Do[sums, {s, list}] or Do[sums, {s, 100}], but then I have trouble incorporating the successive export for each s calculated.

The code:

data = {4.423, 4.45, 4.45, 4.409, 4.423, 4.423, 4.423, 4.409, 4.437,
4.492, 4.492, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.506, 4.506, 4.52,
4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.464, 4.423, 4.381, 4.367, 4.367, 4.367, 4.311,
4.311, 4.27, 4.297, 4.381, 4.381, 4.381, 4.367, 4.395, 4.409,
4.423, 4.45, 4.45, 4.45, 4.409, 4.409, 4.409, 4.409, 4.381, 4.381,
4.381, 4.367, 4.381, 4.409, 4.381, 4.367, 4.367, 4.367, 4.381,
4.367, 4.395, 4.409, 4.409, 4.409, 4.409, 4.381, 4.367, 4.367,
4.395, 4.367, 4.367, 4.367, 4.339, 4.367, 4.353, 4.395, 4.409,
4.409, 4.409, 4.409, 4.395, 4.395, 4.395, 4.395, 4.395, 4.395,
4.381, 4.353, 4.339, 4.325, 4.284, 4.284, 4.284, 4.228, 4.255,
4.284, 4.284, 4.284, 4.284, 4.284, 4.284, 4.186, 4.228, 4.241,
4.255, 4.255, 4.255, 4.27, 4.27, 4.284, 4.284, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116,
4.144, 4.13, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116, 4.13, 4.144,
4.144, 4.144, 4.13, 4.13, 4.13, 4.13, 4.158, 4.144, 4.144, 4.158,
4.158, 4.158, 4.172, 4.186, 4.172, 4.172, 4.172, 4.172, 4.172,
4.158, 4.144, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116, 4.116, 4.101,
4.073, 4.059, 4.087, 4.087, 4.087, 4.087, 4.087, 4.087, 4.073,
4.087, 4.087, 4.087, 4.087, 4.087, 4.101, 4.116, 4.13, 4.13, 4.13,
4.144, 4.158, 4.172, 4.172, 4.172, 4.172, 4.172, 4.172, 4.158,
4.158, 4.172, 4.158, 4.158, 4.158, 4.158, 4.158, 4.172, 4.172,
4.144, 4.144, 4.144, 4.144, 4.172, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214,
4.214, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214, 4.214,
4.241, 4.255, 4.255, 4.255, 4.255, 4.255, 4.27, 4.27, 4.284, 4.284,
4.27, 4.27, 4.27, 4.264, 4.273, 4.343, 4.29, 4.273, 4.273, 4.273,
4.264, 4.238, 4.255, 4.203, 4.194, 4.194, 4.194, 4.212, 4.203,
4.194, 4.186, 4.186, 4.186, 4.186, 4.186, 4.177, 4.177, 4.186,
4.186, 4.186, 4.186, 4.203, 4.212, 4.221, 4.255, 4.255, 4.255,
4.255, 4.221, 4.255, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.36, 4.36,
4.378, 4.386, 4.325, 4.325, 4.325, 4.351, 4.333, 4.325, 4.273,
4.273, 4.273, 4.273, 4.264};

```
fs = Fourier[data];
n = Length[data];
s = {5};
a0f = Abs[fs[[1]]]/Sqrt[n];
af = Abs[fs][[s]];
pf = Arg[fs][[s]];
sums = Table[Sum[af[[j]]*Cos[(2*Pi*x*(s[[j]] - 1))/n - pf[[j]]], {j, 1, 
  Length[s]}] + a0f, {x, 0, 5000}];
export = Export["test.csv", sums];
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Sincerely, Mike

Comment: Don't forget to hit the check mark beside any answers that answer your question, and hitting the up arrow to vote up answers. Welcome to MMA-SE!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is I think a little unclear, but as far as I understand you're almost basically there, you simply need to expand your table some.

```
fs = Fourier[data];
n = Length[data];
s = Range[10];
a0f = Abs[fs[[1]]]/Sqrt[n];
af = Abs[fs][[s]];
pf = Arg[fs][[s]];


sums = Table[Sum[af[[j]]*Cos[(2*Pi*x*(s[[j]] - 1))/n - pf[[j]]], {j, 1, a}] + a0f, {x, 0, 5}, {a, 1, Length@s}]
export = Export["test.csv", sums];
```

This gives me a result of {6,10} values exported to a 6x10 csv...though, It's unclear if you want your sum to also increase as you increase the length of s for each subsequent value, however I assume this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. No - I want the result for each INDIVIDUAL s exported into their individual column, Using range I will ge the SUM of the combined cosine curve for 1-10. So far I have learnt that I could use Table[Table[... to get the part with different columns sorted - now I need the LOOP so that the calculation is done for each s. Perhaps I could delete the s = from the above code that use the Do[s...command?

Comment: Add: The code was designed to give the sum cosine curve so that part is obsolete for what I want right now - just to be clear.

Comment: Could you provide the table code for two different s values as seperate lines/codes/iterations, As the final calculations? I think maybe that’s help me understand ehat you’re looking for, your sum at the moment produces a constant value.

Comment: Thanks for the initiative. I got hold of an answer now. It involved to encapsulate the sum function for a specific value of s and nb of steps forward in a function then call the function in a table to generate the desired output. Full answer can be found @ Mathematica forum ( https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2113265?p_p_auth=6ShEULis );